# How to exclude `.. testcode::` in make html

Tags: python, python-sphinx, doctest

I've a small python and just a few of these files have the `.. testcode::` directive in order to test the python code.

Is there any way to **exclude all** the tests when invoking `make html`?

Comment: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/doctest.html#skipping-tests-conditionally You need to test for the builder as `html`.

Comment: thanks for the answer. So I should add `skipif` in test snippet of ech `rst` file, right? I cannot find an option to add to the `conf.py` file or `SPHINXOPTS` parameter in the `Makefile` to just ignore all the tests in a builder (e.g. `html`).

Comment: Actually that might not be possible, as it appears that the builder name `html` is not available when `conf.py` is read because the builder has not yet been initialized. See note under tags: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#options-for-html-output Instead try the [`only` directive](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#tags) such as `.. only:: not html`. Try that out on one test block and see if that does what you need.

Comment: got it, thanks anyway for the hint :)